# Can Heroku Logplex read from application log files of Heroku apps?

Tags: logging, heroku

Is Heroku Logplex made to read from application log files of Heroku apps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Heroku logplex reads from logs sent to STDOUT or STDERR. It cannot read logs written to a local file.
You need to configure your app to send logs to stdout instead of a file.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I've just discovered the `-l` option of [Heroku buildpack: PHP](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php). So, that makes it configurable at process startup.